# What is the correct way to solve this circular import error with a Flask blueprint?

Tags: python, flask

I had a problem with a circular import, so I moved my blueprint import below my app definition.  However, I'm still having an import error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2217, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1643, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/benjamin/Documents/Projects/website/server/app/app.py", line 15, in <module>
    from views import site
  File "/Users/benjamin/Documents/Projects/website/server/app/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from models import User
  File "/Users/benjamin/Documents/Projects/website/server/app/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from database_setup import db
  File "/Users/benjamin/Documents/Projects/website/server/app/database_setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/benjamin/Documents/Projects/website/server/app/app.py", line 15, in <module>
    from views import site
ImportError: cannot import name site
```

If I move the blueprint import and registration to `if __name__ == '__main__':`, the problem goes away, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from views import site
    app.register_blueprint(site)
    app.run()
```

Is this the right way to solve the problem, or is there another solution?

---

original `app.py` without `__main__` "fix":

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from views import site
app.register_blueprint(site)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

`views.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

site = Blueprint('site', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')

@site.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

`database_setup.py`:

```
from app import app
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {'db': 'mst_website'}    
db = MongoEngine(app)
```

`models.py`:

```
from database_setup import db

class User(db.Document):
    # ...
```

---

My file structure is:

```
/server
  |-- requirements.txt
  |-- env/ (virtual environment)
  |-- app/ (my main app folder)
       |-- static/
       |-- templates/
       |-- __init__.py
       |-- app.py
       |-- database_setup.py
       |-- models.py
       |-- views.py
```

Comment: By placing the import and call to `register_blueprint` inside the if, your blueprint won't be registered if you run your application without executing the file directly (e.g., with uwsgi).

Comment: @dirn Isn't that what I did here by putting the import inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a circular import in your code.  Based on the traceback:

1. `app.py` does `from views import site`
2. `views.py` does `from models import User`
3. `models.py` does `from database_setup import db`
4. `database_setup.py` does `from app import app`
5. `app.py` does `from views import site`

Based on these order of events, the `app.py` you've posted isn't the one that's actually causing your problem.  Right now, `app` hasn't been defined before `views` is imported, so when further down the chain it tries to get `app`, it's not available yet.

You need to restructure your project so that everything that depends on `app` is imported *after* `app` is defined.  From your question, it seems like you think you did, but perhaps there's still an import written above `app` that you missed.

---

Probably unrelated, but you are currently using "relative" imports, which are discouraged.  Rather than doing `from views import site`, etc., you should do an absolute path: `from app.views import site`, or a relative path: `from .views import site`.

---

To answer the initial question of "is using `__main__` to import blueprints a good idea?", it is not.  The problem with that is that the `__main__` guard is *only* executed when you run the module directly.  When you go to deploy this using a real app server such as uWSGI or Gunicorn, none of your blueprints will be imported or registered.